# Angular Universal Deployed To Cloud Function Not Loading Styles or JS

Tags: angular, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2

I have a barebones Angular 11 project with Angular Material for styles. I intend to host this with a Google Cloud Function. When I run the project using `npm run dev:ssr`, it runs without problem. However, after I use AngularFire's `ng deploy` function, it does deploy the universal project as a cloud function but the JS and CSS files are not loaded. See screenshots below.

[image: works fine with serving locally]
vs.

[image: without loading correct files]

So why aren't the styles/js being applied in the cloud function?
If I look in my cloud function logs, I have some 304 error messages.
If I look in the console of the page, I have 403 error codes for requested style/js files.
I noticed that the html has linked the files as shown here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.dbb0bce96e655a5b656e.css">
```

However, if edit the html with an explicit url, it works.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://us-central1-inhouse-dev-ddaad.cloudfunctions.net/ssr/styles.dbb0bce96e655a5b656e.css">
```

You can find my entire project [here on github](https://github.com/Marcusg62/universal-template). I don't know how to fix this issue because I don't know what the source of the issue is.

Comment: Why would you host it as cloud function?????
Cloud functions is not meant to host websites! Use firebase hosting instead.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting

Comment: See comment to answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using Cloud Functions for the purpose that it was designed to. Cloud Functions is a Function as a Service(FaaS) product, which means that it is designed for executing server side functions only, if you want to use Cloud Functions in your app what you can do is deploy the individual functions of your backend to it.

For hosting an entire app in Google Cloud/Firebase, you could use a number of products offered. As per what you shared, I would recommend Either [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs) or [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting). Also, if you are interested you can take a look at the Cloud Functions [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs)

---

EDIT:

As per the comment you shared, Angular Universal will allow you to deploy to **either** Cloud Functions or Firebase Hosting, as described on the documentation you shared, but given that Cloud Functions is a FaaS product what you are trying to do is still not what it was intended to be used for, nor what the developers of Angular Universal intended it to, as they **also have the option for Firebase Hosting as an alternative for hosting apps**.

That being said and as you have shared in the question, you might be able to deploy it, but since this is Cloud Functions and for the reason mentioned above, it's very likely that it will not behave as you expect, and it makes sense that it is unable to link your `href` to `.css` files because that is not a capability that Cloud Functions have.

Comment: Angular Universal is a server side rendering engine for Angular applications. In fact, the AngularFire library (supported by Google) has a predefined script `ng deploy` for deploying to cloud functions. Checkout their documentation on Github. I'm aware it might not be the best solution because of cold start time, but this is a fine use case. https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/universal/cloud-functions.md

Comment: @MarcusGallegos I have edited the answer with some additional arguments after analysing Angular Unversal, please take a look.